# Linq sort by 2 columns with FirstOrDefault

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

I try to sort my Linq query on 2 columns: seq and version:

**table:**

```
id | seq | version
01 | 1   | 1
02 | 1   | 2
03 | 1   | 1
04 | 2   | 2
05 | 2   | 3
06 | 3   | 1
```

**My query:**

```
  var events = from x in db.Events
                         group x by x.Seq into s
                         select s.OrderBy(z => z.Seq).OrderByDescending(z => z.version).FirstOrDefault();
```

**Current result:**

```
id | seq | version
05 | 2   | 3
06 | 3   | 1
02 | 1   | 2
```

**Desired result:**

```
id | seq | version
02 | 1   | 2
05 | 2   | 3
06 | 3   | 1
```

The problem seems to be the combination or 2 orderby and FirstOrDefault(). What is the correct query to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way is to first group by `seq`, then order by `version` and take the desired single result, and finally sort the resulting set by `seq`, like this

```
var events = data
    .GroupBy(x => x.seq, (key, items) => items.OrderByDescending(x => x.version).FirstOrDefault())
    .OrderBy(x => x.seq);
```

Answer (score 2):

**FIXED**

```
var events = (from x in db.Events
           group x by x.Seq into s
           select s.OrderByDescending(z => z.version).FirstOrDefault()).OrderBy(z => z.Seq);
```

See working [Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/SR84Xz)

Comment: It gives still the same result as in my questions

Comment: @JasonB Alex's answer is correct, even the code in your answer is correct

Comment: See working fiddle with your data that produces desired result

Comment: Are you sure you didn't read this answer's use of `ThenByDescending` with the bias that that was what you'd intended when you used `OrderByDescending` and so not change to use this answer correctly?

Comment: @AlexArt. That's why you should always add a short explanation. Code-only answers are considered low-quality and they may end up in the low-quality review queue.

Comment: This doesn't work. Add `Array.Reverse(data);` before the query and see the result.